# How to access virtual machine (Windows Server 2008) from browser?

Tags: azure, geoserver

I am trying out the Free Trial Microsoft Azure.
Basically I created an VM running Windows Server 2008 SP1.

There, I am running GeoServer, being able to access the geoserver from the local browser (eg: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web)

Now, how to access this from a public browser? It has a public IP 13.93.154.109
which I can't even ping it, not to say to access it.

What did I miss out?

**Note**: I tried both classic/non-classic VM, result is the same.
Also, I am aware that there is an OpenGeo Suite out there for Azure. But it costs a lot. What I am trying to do is, to share the VM with the other existing product.

Thanks in advance.

[localhost-from-vm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3FWF.jpg)

P.S: I am able to ping 13.93.154.109:3389 using PsPing instead of normal Ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the port 8080 to allow traffic on your VM.
Depending on how you have created the VM, it can be done in different ways:

- If you have used the Classic workflow, you need to add an endpoint to your cloud service: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints/
- If you have used the Azure Resource Manager workflow, you need to create an inbound rule in the network security group: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal/#create-rules-in-an-existing-nsg

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and resources. But I haven't been able to achieve that. I am using Azure Resource Manager. What I did - add the inbound security rule (only) -- HTTP (TCP/80), RDP(TCP/3389), Custom (TCP/8080). What did I observe, is that, in the Subnets - there is a row record, with address range (10.0.0.0/24), and my security group assigned. Does that mean, that's enough to access my VM with the public IP?
Your patience is appreciated.

Comment: Have you add a rule to open 8080 in the windows firewall, in the VM ?

Comment: Hi Julien, sorry for the late. When you mentioned 'open port 8080 in windows firewall in the VM', does it mean the inbound security rule? Or is it something else? As mentioned in the previous comment, i have 3 inbound security rules now. By using PsPing, i am only able to ping the port 3389.

Comment: Sorry, i feel dumb asking this. I think you meant creating New Rule in the 'Windows Firewall with Advanced Security' setting. I tried that. But result seems to be the same.

Comment: Hi, seems the result is different now. I am able to access port 8080 but there is a different error message. Let me further debug before posting again. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Hi Julien, now it works perfectly. Thanks for your help!
But i am unable to upvote this due to low reputation.